# Loop between two dates. Start and end date(Fetch API)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, loops

I make requests to the bank to get the exchange rate for the interval that are indicated in input.
It turns out the interval [startdate; enddate]
But to make a request to the bank, I need to transfer the selected date to the link in this form: **20191003**

I do it like this 
:

```js
var sdate=startdate.value.split("-").join("");
var edate=enddate.value.split("-").join("");
```

And so I make a request to the bank, the next month falls between the dates.
And I see the following error[image]
This is an error due to the loop, because by its logic it should be like this:
***20190932
20190933 ...***
But I need to make a transition to another month like this:
***20191001
20191002***

But i dont know how,
Here my website where i do this but he on ukraine language
https://yurakhomitsky.github.io/exchange%20rates/

```js
  var startdate=document.getElementById("cdate");
 var enddate=document.getElementById("bdate");
async function currency(e) {
 
 var sdate=startdate.value.split("-").join("");
 var edate=enddate.value.split("-").join("");

  for (var i = Number(sdate); i <= Number(edate); i++){
   console.log(i);
 let url=`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=${currenc.value}&date=${i}&json`;
let response= await fetch(url);
let data =await response.json();
var itemObj={
 rate:data[0].rate,
 exchangedate:data[0].exchangedate
 };
 chartData.series[0].data.push(Number(itemObj.rate.toFixed(2)));
}

Highcharts.chart('container', chartData);
}
```

Comment: Think you could make use of the `momentjs` library

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, what do you think of it?
I can switch to another month without problems, it seems to work

```js
async function currency(e) {


 var sdate=startdate.value;
 var edate=enddate.value;
 sdate=Date.parse(sdate);
 edate=Date.parse(edate);
  for (let i=sdate;i<=edate;i=i+24*60*60*1000){
 let url=`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=${currenc.value}&date=${new Date(i).toISOString().substr(0,10).split("-").join("")}&json`;
let response= await fetch(url);
let data =await response.json();
var itemObj={
 rate:data[0].rate,
 exchangedate:data[0].exchangedate
 };
 chartData.series[0].data.push(Number(itemObj.rate.toFixed(2)));
}

Highcharts.chart('container', chartData);
}
```